# Adding title Dynamically using Google Drive SDK in Python for Mac OS X

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am stuck with a problem.

I want to dynamically assign a title to the file which is being inserted.
I have written Google Drive API code using Google Drive SDK in Python for Mac OS X.

```
media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='image/png', resumable=True)
body = {
 'title': 'title',
 'description': 'description',
 'mimeType': 'image/png'
}
```

Now, how do I assign title as my Filename without extension while insertion?

Ex. : Filename = abc.png

So, the title should automatically be assigned as   abc

Comment: err 'title': 'abc' . Am I missing something?

Comment: i want it to be dynamically assigned....it should read my filename which is going to be uploaded and set the filename as its title

Comment: title = 'abc'            body = {'title': title}

Comment: just assume that I don't know what my filename is....

Comment: How can you not know? That makes no sense. I think you need to expand your question to describe what it is your app is doing.

Comment: i am automating this task...
it would be reading the files in my current directory and upload those files to google drive..

So, I cannot statically assign names to each and every file.

Comment: That's obvious. So 'title': FILENAME ? Is your question about the Drive Sdk, or just how do you split a string in Python?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use multipart to upload the metadata to the file.

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#multipart

I haven't tried it with a resumable upload but the idea should be the same.   I googled Python and multipart came up with a few examples.